I want to automate VeriFone configuration process in my site (Is ther any API in which I can get all my Verifone central panel data)
Currently we have a scenario like user will add Verifone User Id, Verifone API Key and Verifone Roles in the user profile and other details like Verifone URL, Organization Id, Payment Contract Id, Scope Id(Optional), Public Key and Public Key Alias in the another module for properly working of Verifone card and Pay by link transaction. So for these configuration merchant need to gather all the info from their Verifone Central Portal and it is too many things they need to configure. So does Verifone provide any API which gives all the details based on token or something, so we can automate that process based on that API and merchant do not need to configure all those things manually and it will improve merchants experience.
If i get any API in which i can share required data and get all the details related to my verifone central data like organization id and other stuff mentioned in the question.
